# Edit the text in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with a title, are there methods for the user to modify this title by clicking on it and pressing CTRL simultaneously?

```
<div class="panel-participants-title">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
        {{thread.title.substring(1)}}
    </h3>
</div>
```

It's possible tu just use HTML and CSS for do that ?

Comment: `are there methods for the user to modify this title by clicking on it and pressing CTRL simultaneously` **YES**. `It's possible tu just use HTML and CSS for do that ?` **NO**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `contenteditable="true"` attribute, but i'm not sure what do you want to do with that edited text?

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.